# How to properly implement threading while writing out to a csv?

Tags: python, multithreading, csv

I'm pulling commit data from the `Gerrit` API, and the commit number is in the 226,000 range.  Where I have to make a request to an endpoint for each and every commit, this is understandable taking a long time.  I was wondering how I could best implement threading into my current process.

I have two classes, a `Project` class, which drills down and retrieves all commits associated with it, and saves them out as a `Commit` object that contains all the information necessary to then loop through and get the `json` associated with it.  I am pulling them all into a big list, and then iterating through to call the `get_data` and `write_data` methods.

```
class Project(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.commits = []

    def add_commits(self, changes_list):
        for change in changes_list:
            change_id=change['change_id'],
            revision_list=change['revisions']
            self.commits.extend([Commit(rid, change_id)
                                 for rid in revision_list.keys()])

    def return_results(self, ger_obj, start=0):
        self.ger = ger_obj
        while True:
            endpoint = (r'/changes/?q=project:{project}&o=ALL_REVISIONS&'
                        r'S={num}'.format(
                project=self.name,
                num=start
            ))
            logging.info('Endpoint: {}'.format(endpoint))
            try:
                changes = ger_obj.get(endpoint)
                self.add_commits(changes_list=changes)
            except HTTPError:
                break
            start += 500
            try:
                if not changes[-1].get('_more_changes'):
                    break
            except IndexError:
                break


class Commit(object):
    def __init__(self, rev_id, change_id):
        self.rev_id = rev_id
        self.change_id = change_id

    def get_data(self, ger_obj):
        endpoint = (r'/changes/{c_id}/revisions/{r_id}/commit'.format(
            c_id=self.change_id[0],
            r_id=self.rev_id
        ))
        try:
            self.data = ger_obj.get(endpoint)
        except HTTPError as e:
            logging.warning('Endpoint: {} did not return data'.format(
                endpoint
            ))
        else:
            self.data['commitid'] = self.data.get('commit')
            self.data['name'] = self.data.get('committer')['name']
            self.data['email'] = self.data.get('committer')['email']
            self.data['date'] = self.data.get('committer')['date']
            hash = md5()
            hash.update(json.dumps(self.data).encode('utf-8'))
            self.data['etl_checksum_md5'] = hash.hexdigest()
            self.data['etl_process_status'] = ETL_PROCESS_STATUS
            self.data['etl_datetime_local'] = ETL_DATETIME_LOCAL
            self.data['etl_pdi_version'] = ETL_PDI_VERSION
            self.data['etl_pdi_build_version'] = ETL_PDI_BUILD_VERSION
            self.data['etl_pdi_hostname'] = ETL_PDI_HOSTNAME
            self.data['etl_pdi_ipaddress'] = ETL_PDI_IPADDRESS
            self.data['message'] = self.data['message'].replace('\n', ' ').replace('|', '[pipe]')

    def write_data(self, writer):
        writer.writerow(self.data)
```

I'm thinking that the best place to implement the threads is once I have all the commits in a list and am ready to iterate over them:

```
projects = [Project(value['id']) for value in project_data.values()]
    for project in projects[:10]:
        if project.name in bad_names.keys():
            project.name = bad_names[project.name]
        project.return_results(rest)
        all_commits.extend(project.commits)

    fieldnames = get_fieldnames(
        'ods_gerrit.staging_gerrit_commits',
        REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO)

    with open('testfile.csv', 'wb') as outf:
        writer = DictWriter(
        outf,
        fieldnames=fieldnames,
        extrasaction='ignore',
        delimiter='|'
    )
# Implement Threading?
        for commit in all_commits:
            commit.get_data(rest)
            try:
                commit.write_data(writer=writer)
            except AttributeError:
                continue
            except Exception:
                print commit.data, 'caused an exception.'
                continue
```

I've read a few threading tutorials, and am unsure as to how to properly do this.  I'm particularly worried about overwriting data due to improper locking.

Comment: write to N different files ... and then merge after all threads finish ...

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use threading when writing to a single file. And before deciding that you need threading to improve performance you should *measure* what the actual bottleneck is. Network traffic can easily have more latency than disk access.